# Swift Key window subview disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabcontroller

I am experiencing some weird behavior with a button I am trying to implement in my app. I have a 'compose post' button that I am adding to the key window of the app. I want to create the button and hide it in certain scenarios like when the navigation controller pushes a new view controller (i.e. clicking on a post). The app is setup like this:

`Main` is a storyboard that is a custom UITabController of type `MainTabViewController` that has 4 tabs, each a UINavigationController that has a container that is of type `BaseViewController`.

In the `viewDidLoad` function of `MainTabViewController` I create the compose button and add it to the key window as a subview like this:

```
 func createButton(){
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        postButtonContainer = FanMenu...
        keyWindow?.addSubview(postButtonContainer)
 }
```

And in `BaseViewController`  I use `viewWillDisappear` to hide the compose button (i.e. when post is clicked on) and then `viewWillAppear` to show the compose button by setting the `isHidden` to true or false.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    ComposeButtonManager.shared.hidePostButton()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    ComposeButtonManager.shared.showPostButton()
}
```

The issue is happening only after I crash close the app after booting up from Xcode. What's happening is that when I reopen after crash closing - the app will load fine and present the compose button, but if I navigate from a tab and then back to that same tab, the compose button is not showing. And if I click a post and navigate back to `BaseViewController` subclass the button will re appear. I am not sure why the button is hiding after the tab bar switches, when all the UIViewControllers call to unhide the button when their view will appear.

When I run the project on my phone from Xcode, I can switch around tabs and the button won't disappear, its only happening after I crash close and disconnect from Xcode, not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @LeoDabus yes I run the project from Xcode, everything works fine, after I crash close and disconnect from Xcode I am running into the issue explained above

Comment: @LeoDabus through TestFlight?

Comment: Sorry I thought it was macOS. never mind. My bad